# Oracle Weblogic 12.1.2 Node Manager Status java.io.IOException

Tags: java, windows, oracle, weblogic

I'm trying to configure the new wls 12.1.2 with JDK 1.7 r45 on Windows 2008 R2

No problem with the admin console.
But i have problem with the node manager, it is on the same server (all-in-one).
On Machine voice (domainname/environment/machines) I check the status of my machine node manager status and I get :

Inactive
java.io.IOException

No error displayed on adminserver.log and nodemanager.log
The port 5556 is alive and tested with telnet.
With procmon I don't see errors or problem.
The instances are executed with the same user that is localadmin

What can I do to invastigate/debug it?
What could be the problem for you?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you don use SSL you have to modify the property SecureListener in the file nodemanager.properties:

```
SecureListener=false

(false=plain, true=SSL)
```